# On execution of a ghidra script, errors from a non-existent script (which once existed) are displayed in the console

Tags: ghidra

I just stumbled over this error, of which I could find no mentioning anywhere in the net.

In my case, the (java) script once existed, but was renamed.  However, Ghidra continued to complain about errors in it.

Using the refresh button in the script manager did not help. File system search brought no result, the old script did not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In the script-manager, there is a button "manage script directories", which opens the "bundle manager".
It has a refresh button, too. This helped.